# MvxRecyclerView items have null ViewModel

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In my xamarin.droid application I have next layout with `MvxRecyclerView`

```
<MvxRecyclerView 
      ...
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/symbol_item_fragment"
      local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items" />
```

`symbol_item_fragment` is defined as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment 
      ...
      android:name="mobile.droid.company.fragments.SymbolItemFragment" />
```

and I define `SymbolItemFragment` as

```
[Register("mobile.droid.company.fragments.SymbolItemFragment")]
public class SymbolItemFragment : MvxFragment<SymbolItemViewModel>
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.symbol_item_view, null);

       //ViewModel is null

       return view;        
    }
}
```

I can see that Fragments are rendered properly, but ViewModel is not defined for them for some reason.

What am I missing?

Comment: MvxFragments are not inflatable through XML, or well they are, but they won't ever have a ViewModel attached.

Comment: Maybe this is a typo but I see you fragment is called `SymbolItemFragment` but your ViewModel is `SymboltemViewModel` missing the `I` in Item in the ViewModel.

Comment: @Cheesebaron got it. In this case, how to set all bindings in the codebehind for ItemsSource?

Comment: @pnavk it's just a type. Thank you.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Is there any way to use `MvxRecyclerView` and code behind binding for item templates? The only thing I'm concerned about - during refactoring xml bindings will become invalid soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CheeseBaron said in the comment to the question

> MvxFragments are not inflatable through XML, or well they are, but
>   they won't ever have a ViewModel attached.

So, no solution for this approach so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think the extension method `EnsureBindingContextIsSet()` will solve it.

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    this.EnsureBindingContextIsSet (savedInstanceState);
    base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.symbol_item_view, null);

   return view;        
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. ViewModel property is still null. Does it make the difference if the base activity is `MvxActivity`, instead of `MvxFragmentActivity`?

Comment: Hmm ok. Then I'd guess, the pain point is the use of fragments within a recycler view. I'm not sure if this scenario is implemented. I have never used it this way.

Comment: Thanks. I was wrong about binding in layout, it doesn't work too. If nothing will help, I'll go with RecyclerView probably.